# TypeScript Generics with React Function Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following component structure:

```js
export interface SearchFilterJobsProps<J = JobPosting> {
  unwrap?: boolean;
  jobs?: {
    data: J[];
    component?: React.ComponentType | React.ElementType;
  };
  searchMatchProps?: (keyof J)[];
}

export type SearchFilterJobsType<T = JobPosting> = React.FC<SearchFilterJobsProps<T>>;

export const SearchFilterJobs: SearchFilterJobsType = <Z extends JobPosting>(
  {
    jobs,
    searchMatchProps,
    className,
    children,
    ...rest
  }: SearchFilterJobsProps<Z> & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => { ... };
```

I have set it up like this, because I would like this component to handle various data structures. But I seem to have made some mistakes, because when I am attempting to use it:

```js
<SearchFilterJobs<SpecificJobProps> jobs={{data: specificJobs}} />
```

TypeScript tells me: `TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting the component const to a function declaration.
I think that should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
export const SearchFilterJobs: SearchFilterJobsType = ...
```

will pick the default type param for SearchFilterJobsType. What's on the right side doesn't matter - the type annotation, if provided, must be complete.

Simplest solution in this case is to use `satisfies` instead of an annotation on the constant:

```
export type SearchFilterJobsType<T = JobPosting> = React.FC<SearchFilterJobsProps<T>>;

export const SearchFilterJobs = (<Z extends JobPosting>(
  {
    jobs,
    searchMatchProps,
    className,
    children,
    ...rest
  }: SearchFilterJobsProps<Z> & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => { 
... }) satisfies React.FC<SearchFilterJobsProps<T>>;
```